# making a simple history function in C shell program

Tags: c

this command will list the recent commands (up to 100) that have been used. The most recent will be at the bottom. Need a little advice on where to start. I know for sure i need a for loop to print the history. One hint was a 2D array but i'm not to familiar with those.

```
  MAX_HIS_SIZE 100
  char history[MAX_HIS_SIZE]; 
  int size = 0; 

   //history function
   for(int p =1; p < size; p++)
   printf(" %s ",history[p]);
   printf("\n");
```

Comment: assign your array with some values!

Answer (score 1):

`char history[MAX_HIS_SIZE]` keeps characters. Use `char* history[MAX_HIS_SIZE]` to access the commands, if your commands are not only one characters.

If you want to access to history any time you wanted, keep a an index that points last command entered. Whenever you wanted to list the history, just count down from that point, until you reach a `NULL` which indicates end of the list. And access your index through modulo operation, so you can rewind and access the oldest command, replace it with the newest command.

```
const int MAX_HIS_SIZE = 100;
int last = 0;
char * history[MAX_HIS_SIZE];

 void newCmd(char* cmd) {
     history[last%MAX_HIS_SIZE]=cmd;
     last++;
 }

void listHistory(){
    for(int i = last,  limit = 0; history[i] != NULL && limit != MAX_HIS_SIZE ; i = (i -1)%MAX_HIS_SIZE, limit++)
        printf(" %s ",history[i]);

}
```

Comment: should the newCmd be called right before parsing my code?

Comment: That is up to your code. If you want to keep as it is entered, you can do it before. But if you want to validate the command first or keep only a part of the command, after parsing the command you call `newCmd(char* validatedCmd)` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
// you want an array of strings.  since each string is a different
// length, allocate them with malloc (and free them later)
// You also want to use a circular buffer:

struct History {
  char** lines;
  int max_size;
  int begin;
}

void initialize_history(struct History* history, int size) {
  history->max_size = size;
  history->lines = malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    history->lines[i] = NULL;
  }
}

void add_to_history(struct History* history, char* commandline) {
  if (history->lines[history->begin] != NULL) {
    free(history->lines[history->begin]);
  }
  history->lines[history->begin] = commandline;
  history->begin = (history->begin + 1) % history->max_size;
}

void print_history(struct History* history) {
  int i;
  int begin = history->begin;
  for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (history->lines[begin] != NULL) {
      printf("%s\n", history->lines[begin]);
    }
    ++begin;
    if (begin >= history->max_size) {
      begin = 0;
    }
  }
}
void free_history(struct History* history) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (history->lines[i] != NULL) {
      free(history->lines[i]);
    }
  }
  free(history->lines);
}
```